# Using linear regression (lm) in R caret, how do I force the intercept through 0?

Tags: r, r-caret, lm

I'm trying to use R caret to perform cross-validation of my linear regression models. In some cases I want to force the intercept through 0. I have tried the following, using the standard lm syntax:

```
regressControl  <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",
                        number = 4,
                        repeats = 5
                        )                      

regress         <- train(y ~ 0 + x,
               data = myData,
               method  = "lm",
               trControl = regressControl)

Call:
lm(formula = .outcome ~ ., data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     x 
-0.0009585    0.0033794  `
```

This syntax seems to work with the standard 'lm' function but not within the caret package. Any suggestions?

```
test <- lm(y ~ 0 + x,
       data = myData)


Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + x, data = myData)

Coefficients:
x 
0.003079
```

Comment: I believe you want the formula `y ~ -1 + x` to explicitly exclude the intercept.

Comment: @aichao Both of these work in most functions, but `caret`'s implementation makes it difficult without editing the source code.

Comment: @Chrisss: thanks! nice to know.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394855/fit-a-no-intercept-model-in-caret

Comment: If you `scale` all your data, your intercept will become [effectively] zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `tuneGrid` parameter in `caret::train`.

```
regressControl  <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",
                    number = 4,
                    repeats = 5
                    ) 

regress <- train(mpg ~ hp,
           data = mtcars,
           method  = "lm",
           trControl = regressControl, 
           tuneGrid  = expand.grid(intercept = FALSE))
```

Use `getModelInfo("lm", regex = TRUE)[[1]]$param` to see all the things you could have tweaked in `tuneGrid` (in the lm case, the only tuning parameter is the intercept). It's silly that you can't simply rely on `formula` syntax, but alas.

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you. (I had also tried using 'trace' to modify the formula but without any success - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394855/fit-a-no-intercept-model-in-caret)

Comment: @SarahM I believe the `caret` source code has changed since the trace answer was made, therefore it wouldn't be appropriate anymore.

Comment: @SarahM You should accept this as the answer. it's good in at least caret v6.0.76