# Fit a no intercept binary model in caret

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, r-caret, intercept

Let's take data :

```
y <- sample(0:1, 125, T)
x <- data.frame(rnorm(125), rexp(125))
```

I want to perform cross validation on data above, without intercept. To exclude intercept in linear models in caret we just need to use : `tuneGrid = expand.grid(intercept = FALSE)`. However when applying this to binary models :

```
library(caret)
train(as.factor(y) ~ .,
           data = cbind(y,x),
           method = "glm",
           family = binomial(link = 'logit'),
           tuneGrid = expand.grid(intercept = FALSE),
           trControl = trainControl(
             method = "cv",
             number = 5
           )
)
```

I get error :

```
Error: The tuning parameter grid should have columns parameter
```

My question is : Do we have any possibility to omit intercept in caret binary models ?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41730532/6574038 ?

Comment: Hey jay.sf! I'm using exactly same code they are using and as you can see in my question - it's not working in binary case.

Comment: Hi John, I was looking at r-caret questions and saw this. I think the linked question should have a working answer for you.